Integral the product of exponential function and Bessel functions
How to solve $\int_{0}^{R} r e^{a r^2}J_{0}(br)dr$. The solution of $R=\infty$ can be found in
How do I integrate this exponential + Bessel function term?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413253/definite-integral-involving-modified-bessel-function-of-first-kind-exponentials?rq=1

$$\int_0^x \  e^{a \ \xi^2} \ J_0(b \ \xi) \, d\xi \ = \ \frac{1}{b}\ e^{a x^2} \left( \text{LommelU}\left(0,2 i a x^2,b x\right) +\text{LommelU}\left(1,i a x^2,b x\right)\right)$$
$$\text{LommelU}(n, x, y) =\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{2 k+n} J_{2 k+n}(y)$$
Prudnikov et al . "Integrals and Series Vol 2, p.39 , 1.8.2.4"
Other definitions see
Lommel ODE
